# How to center content in footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

I am building a website using wordpress theme. I have two elements (one floated left, second floated right) in the footer. I need to make it centered (the second one below the first one) when I resize the browser window. I tried giving the `<p>` and `<div>` tag a class and then style it to `float:none;` - hovewer you cann check that It didn't really work on the webpage. I also attach a picture of how I want it to be..

[WEBPAGE](http://svycarsky-dum-responsive.geneweb.cz/)

```
<div class="site-info">
  <div style="margin:0 auto; width: 75%;">
    <p style="float:left;">&copy; Copyright <?= date('Y'); ?> Hotel Švýcarský Dům</p>
    <div style="float:right;">Naleznete nás na sociálních sítích: 
      <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 0 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/gplus.png" /></a>
      <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 5px 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/facebook.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div><!-- .site-info -->
```

[image: THIS IS HOW I WANT IT TO LOOK LIKE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated code. with a screen less than 600px, the divs will go on top of each other. This probably will need tweaking to fit on your site.

```css
#left {
  float: left;
}
#right {
  float: right;
}
#center {
  text-align: center;
}
#container {
  margin-left: 12.5%;
  margin-right: 12.5%;
}
.imagefloat {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: -4px 5px 0 5px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .nofloat {
    width: 100%!important;
    text-align: center;
    float: none!important;
  }
  .imagefloat {
    float: none!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="site-info">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left" class="nofloat">&copy; Copyright
      <?=d ate( 'Y'); ?>Hotel Švýcarský Dům</div>
    <div id="right" class="nofloat">
      <a class="imagefloat" href="">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/gplus.png" />
      </a>
      <a class="imagefloat" href="">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/facebook.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="center">Naleznete nás na sociálních sítích:</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok - I've just noticed your html needs restricting for it to work anyway so will update answer with that

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add align-text:center to one of the divs and a p tag to put the images on a new line

```html
<div class="site-info">
  <div style="text-align:center; width: 75%;">
    <p >&copy; Copyright <?= date('Y'); ?> Hotel Švýcarský Dům</p>
    <div >Naleznete nás na sociálních sítích: 
      <p><a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/gplus.png" /></a>
      <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/facebook.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you kept your `float:left` and `float:right` as inline styling so you will need to move the left and right float to an external css as you can't override inline styling with just css.

Secondly, Add a separate class for the left and right, say `class="float-left"` and `class="float-right"` and then use media query to switch properties for the classes like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .float-left  {
    float: none;
  }
  .float-right  {
    float: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .float-left  {
    float: left;
  }
  .float-right  {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Thirdly, to center the footer text on smaller screens, just add `text-align: center` to the above media query like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .site-info  {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .float-left  {
    float: none;
  }
  .float-right  {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Lastly, add the icons and text within a `<p></p>` tag so they will line-break accordingly.

Comment: Could you edit it with the use of !importang tag please? @Andrew Lyndem

Comment: Apparently, !important tags can't override inline-stylin so using inline-styles is out of the question unless you use javascript to manipulate your inline stylings. I have edited out that !important tag part as that was wrong.